# CentOS7 Apache2.4 http2

Tags: apache, openssl, http2

CentOS7 + Apache/2.4.6でhttp2でアクセスできるように設定しております。
こちら参考にしております。
https://blog.apar.jp/linux/5200/

ApacheとSSLの設定は終わっているのですが、http2のモジュールをうまく組み込めておりません。
そもそもmod_http2.soなるソケットがなかったり、その手のconfigファイルが作成されなかったりで、http2自体を活性化できない状態です。
手順書的なものを探しているのですが、どなたか指南いただけますでしょうか。

```
vi /usr/local/src/httpd-2.4.25/config.nice
```

という感じでApacheインストール時のコンフィギャレーションを確認すると、"--enable-http2" \というようにhttp2を使える準備はできている段階です。
ただモジュール一覧には出てきておりません。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

mod_http2 は [Available in version 2.4.17 and later](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_http2.html) となっており 2.4.6 では使用できないと思います。

ご覧になっているページと同じ httpd-2.4.23 で試すと `/usr/local/apache2/modules/mod_http2.so` にモジュールがインストールされました。

Comment: ありがとうございます。基本的なところ見落としておりました。
バージョンを最新Apache/2.4.25にして構築しました。ありがとうございます。